# EventSource named events using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, eventsource

I'm trying to use an `EventSource` with **Typescript** but cannot type correctly the response when using named events.

I tried

```js
const evtSource = new EventSource('/my-url');

const parseMyEvent = (evt: Event) => {
  const data: MyDataInterface = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  console.log(data)
}

evtSource.addEventListener('my-event', parseMyEvent);
```

Fails, because `Event` has no property **data**

```js
const evtSource = new EventSource('/my-url');

const parseMyEvent = (evt: MessageEvent) => {
  const data: MyDataInterface = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  console.log(data)
}

evtSource.addEventListener('my-event', parseMyEvent);
```

Fails on `evtSource.addEventListener('my-event', parseMyEvent)`, with "No overload matches this call.
".

I know that `MessageEvent` is a generic interface, but what should I use as its type?

I'm using TS 3.5.3 so I tried to install the external type `@types/eventsource` with no luck too (I know, it is for the polyfill EventSource lib, but I tried)

When using the generic `evtSource.onMessage = fn` it works without any problems

It should be possible to type the listener/response of a EventSource event in TS, but how?

Comment: Looks like there is a generic on `EventSource.addEventListener` `addEventListener<K extends keyof EventSourceEventMap>(type: K, ....` but it but it only accepts `"error" | "message" | "open"` so that's not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

The below code should work. Basically, you are using TypeScript's [Type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and let the compiler trust you that the underlying event is actually an object of type `MessageEvent`:

```
const evtSource = new EventSource('/my-url');

const parseMyEvent = (evt: Event) => {
  const messageEvent = (evt as MessageEvent);  // <== This line is Important!!
  const data: MyDataInterface = JSON.parse(messageEvent.data);
  console.log(data)
}

evtSource.addEventListener('my-event', parseMyEvent);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `addEventListener` method on `EventSource` has a generic that refers to a type mapping interface (`EventSourceEventMap`).  As mentioned in the comments.  the generic initially only accepts `"error" | "message" | "open"`, but that's because those are the only types defined in the map *by default*.  The intent is that you augment the map with your own types for whatever custom events you are adding.

So in your case, what you need is:

```
declare global {
  interface EventSourceEventMap {
    ['my-event']: MessageEvent<MyDataInterface>;
  }
}
```

With that, typescript will not only know that the message passed to `my-event` *does* have a `data` property, it will know the type of that property as well.

Comment: This worked for me, except that `MyDataInterface` in the above code should always be `string`. The MessageEvent interface is for more general use than just SSE. In the specific context of SSE, the data property is always a string, which may contain a serialized object.